# Merge two hashes and sum nested hashes within each

Tags: ruby, hash

I have two hashes:

```
g_record = {"4-2014"=>{:total_conversions=>0, :total_cost=>0.0}, "5-2014"=>{:total_conversions=>0, :total_cost=>189.8}, "6-2014"=>{:total_conversions=>0, :total_cost=>474.18}}

b_record = {"4-2014"=>{:total_conversions=>7, :total_cost=>639.7}, "5-2014"=>{:total_conversions=>5, :total_cost=>298.03}}
```

My desired output is:

```
combined_record = {"4-2014"=>{:total_conversions=>7, :total_cost=>639.7}, "5-2014"=>{:total_conversions=>5, :total_cost=>487.83}, "6-2014"=>{:total_conversions=>0, :total_cost=>474.18}}
```

I've had to combine hashes and sum values before and have been trying variations of

```
g_record.merge(b_record) {|a, b, c| b + c}
```

But this time I don't understand how I should get inside the intial hashes to run something like that.  I feel like I should be able to do something like

```
g_record.merge(b_record).each {|e| e.merge {|a, b, c| b + c}
```

But I know that is incorrect.

Comment: What gives `:total_conversions=>0` in the desired output?

Comment: Thanks @sawa, my apologies, error on my part adding up the output.  I forgot bing had a few conversions.  Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do :

```
merged_hash = g_record.merge(b_record) do |_, o, n|
  o.merge(n) { |_, o1, n1| o1 + n1 }
end

merged_hash 
# => {"4-2014"=>{:total_conversions=>7, :total_cost=>639.7},
#     "5-2014"=>{:total_conversions=>5, :total_cost=>487.83},
#     "6-2014"=>{:total_conversions=>0, :total_cost=>474.18}}
```

Comment: Thanks Arup!  Ahh I was on the right track iterating over those hashes but couldn't figure out that second merge.  Much appreciated!